# How to add directories to Cygwin gcc default search path

Tags: windows, gcc, path, cygwin

I'm a bit of a noob at working with compilers. I want to add an arbitrary directory on my win 8 C:\ drive to the Cygwin gcc default search path.

Here is what I have tried so far. Using `gcc --help` I found the commands `-print-search-dirs` and `-B <directory>` ("add directory to the compiler's search path").

Using the former command output this:
`install: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/
programs: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.
9.2/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/:/usr/li
b/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-p
c-cygwin/bin/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../.
./../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/
libraries: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4
.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_6
4-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-p
c-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.
9.2/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-p
c-cygwin/4.9.2/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../..
/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../:/lib/:/usr/
lib/`

The full path to `/usr` is `C:\cygwin64\usr`. The directory I want to add is `c:\directory` So I tried `gcc -B /../directory` and other variations, but I get error

`gcc: fatal error: no input files`
`compilation terminated`

Seems like it thinks I'm trying to compile something. I want to permanently add a directory to the list of default search paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues at play here.

The first problem has to do with the fact that Cygwin views the top of its directory tree `/` to be within the Windows directory `C:\cygwin64`.  As a result, you are unable to move above that point in the filesystem. The solution is to go through Cygwin's directory `/cygdrive`, which is the access point where all Windows disk drives are mounted.  You can access the top-level Windows directory `C:\` from Cygwin as `/cygdrive/c`. So for the problem above, instead of using `gcc -B /../directory`, try using `gcc -B /cygdrive/c/directory`.

The second issue is that of adding directories to the search path, versus telling it to compile a specific source file.  Given the date of this question, I assume you've solved that part of the problem at this point?

Comment: Cant remember how I dealt with this, or what I needed it for. Looks like a good answer though. Thanks